angular 17 primNg component
i have this component from PrimNg i need to prevent user to select some option
`<p-treeSelect 
    class="w-full md:w-20rem" 
    containerStyleClass="w-full" 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedNodes" 
    [options]="nodes" 
    display="chip" 
    [metaKeySelection]="false" 
    selectionMode="checkbox" 
    placeholder="Select Item" />`


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

if you want to prevent the selection of this p-treeSelect control. you can disable this control using [disabled]="true". Or you can check any other property from the primeNg documentation.
